# .Net Regex Lookahead Group with \Z (end of line) exception

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

I think I've found a bug in the .NET Regex engine and wondered if anyone else has encountered it, or if it's somehow expected behaviour.

It occurs when matching the end of input <strike>character</strike> assertion `\Z` inside a group of alternatives `[]` inside a lookahead group `(?=)` as in this example expression which throws an exception when it is created.

```
Regex test = new Regex(@"(?=[\Z])");
```

The exception returned is `parsing "(?=[\Z])" - Unrecognized escape sequence \Z.`

<strike>However the Regex `[\Z]` works</strike>, as does `(?=\Z)`

<strike>The workaround is easy enough, using `(?=[]|\Z)` with whatever other alternative characters were required in the alternative group, but it's still odd.</strike>

*Edit: I think there must have been a typo in my original tests, since as nhahtdh points out, the above patterns do in fact throw the exception.*

Tested in .NET 4.5 with C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you claim that `@"[\Z]"` work, but from my testing on ideone (which is currently running on .NET 4.0.30319.17020), it throws the same exception as `@"(?=[\Z])"`:

```
System.ArgumentException: parsing '[\Z]' - Unrecognized escape sequence Z.
  at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanCharEscape () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanCharClass (Boolean caseInsensitive, Boolean scanOnly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  [...]
```

By the way, `(?=[]|\Z)` also throws exception, since it tries to parse a character class consisting of `]`, `|` and encounter the invalid escape sequence `\Z`.

Checking the code of [`RegexParser.ScanCharEscape`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.RegularExpressions/src/System/Text/RegularExpressions/RegexParser.cs#L1491), except for ECMAScript mode (`!UseOptionE()`) the code throws exception if it encounters `\` followed by a word character which doesn't form a known escape sequence (note that in .NET, word character is not restricted to only `A-Za-z0-9_`, but also include other word character in Unicode).

```
            default:
                if (!UseOptionE() && RegexCharClass.IsWordChar(ch))
                    throw MakeException(SR.Format(SR.UnrecognizedEscape, ch.ToString()));
                return ch;
```

This is probably a design decision to allow future extension to the escape syntax without breaking existing code base when people move on to newer version of .NET framework. Java also follows the same design principle in their `Pattern` class, but it only throws exception for unrecognized escape sequence for `A-Za-z`. On the other hand, JavaScript/ECMAScript doesn't have such restriction, and it interprets unrecognized escape sequence as the character following the `\`.

Back to the problem in the question, note that `\Z` is end of input *assertion*, i.e. it matches empty string. An assertion is not a character, so it makes no sense to put it inside character class. Use alternation `|` if you want to specify it along a character class.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, thank you. Part of my original confusion was due to my earlier tests giving me a false positive and leading me to believe that `[\Z]` was valid, when as you've pointed out and explained, it is not.

Answer (score 2):

You have a misunderstanding of what `\Z` is...for it is a **pattern** *anchor* escape and **not an actual character**; hence the exception is valid when trying to use it in a **character** set (`[ ]`).

It can be used to match `\n` as long as the `\n` exists at the end of the data but it is not a `\n` character.

To quote MSDN ([Anchors in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx#EndOrNOnly)):

> The \Z anchor specifies that a match must occur at the end of the
>   input string, or before \n at the end of the input string. It is
>   identical to the $ anchor, except that \Z ignores the
>   RegexOptions.Multiline option. Therefore, in a multiline string, it
>   can only match the end of the last line, or the last line before \n.
>
> Note that \Z matches \n but does not match \r\n (the CR/LF character
>   combination). To match CR/LF, include \r?\Z in the regular expression
>   pattern.

Comment: I was aware that \Z was a zero-length anchor, although I realise I did call it a character in the question. Oops.